# How to get id of the row which was selected by aggregate function?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have next data:

```
id | name | amount | datefrom
---------------------------
3  | a    |  8     | 2018-01-01
4  | a    |  3     | 2018-01-15 10:00
5  | b    |  1     | 2018-02-20
```

I can group result with the next query:

```
select name, max(amount) from table group by name
```

But I need the `id` of selected row too. Thus I have tried:

```
select max(id), name, max(amount) from table group by name
```

And as it was expected it returns:

```
id | name | amount
-----------
4  | a    |  8
5  | b    |  1
```

**But I need the id to have `3` for the amount of `8`:**

```
id | name | amount
-----------
3  | a    |  8
5  | b    |  1
```

Is this possible?

PS. This is required for billing task. At some day `2018-01-15` configuration of `a` was changed and user consumes some resource 10h with the amount of `8` and rests the day 14h -- `3`. I need to count such a day by the maximum value. Thus row with `id = 4` is just ignored for 2018-01-15 day. (for next day 2018-01-16 I will bill the amount of `3`)
So I take for billing the row:

```
3  | a    |  8     | 2018-01-01
```

And if something is wrong with it. I must report that row with `id == 3` is wrong.

But when I used aggregation function the information about `id` is lost.

Would be awesome if this is possible:

```
select current(id), name, max(amount) from table group by name
select aggregated_row(id), name, max(amount) from table group by name
```

Here `agg_row` refer to the row which was selected by aggregation function `max`

**UPD**
I resolve the task as:

```
SELECT 
    (
       SELECT id FROM t2 
       WHERE id = ANY ( ARRAY_AGG( tf.id ) ) AND amount = MAX( tf.amount ) 
    ) id,
    name, 
    MAX(amount) ma,
    SUM( ratio )
FROM t2  tf
GROUP BY name
```

**UPD**
It would be much better to use [window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52556512/4632019)

Comment: Concerning your UPDATE: The operator would be `int = ANY(int[])` but with `DISTINCT ON` there's no need for the subquery.

Comment: @S-Man: May you please write how it will looks withing SQL?

Comment: The operator is demonstrated at this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=faf54fdfd929e524ad6cb728fcf8142f but I am really not able to get your "UPDATE" query work without rebuild it completely - there are too many issues... It is way too complicated :D

Comment: @S-Man: Thanks. Now I fix my query. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52556260/4632019) is it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways, see below:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE test (
    id integer, name text, amount numeric, datefrom timestamptz
);

COPY test FROM STDIN (FORMAT csv);
3,a,8,2018-01-01
4,a,3,2018-01-15 10:00
5,b,1,2018-02-20
6,b,1,2019-01-01
\.
```

### Method 1. using DISTINCT ON (PostgreSQL-specific)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name)
  id, name, amount
FROM test
ORDER BY name, amount DESC, datefrom ASC;
```

### Method 2. using window functions

```
SELECT id, name, amount FROM (
  SELECT *, row_number() OVER (
    PARTITION BY name
    ORDER BY amount DESC, datefrom ASC) AS __rn
  FROM test) AS x
WHERE x.__rn = 1;
```

### Method 3. using corelated subquery

```
SELECT id, name, amount FROM test
WHERE id = (
  SELECT id FROM test AS t2
  WHERE t2.name = test.name
  ORDER BY amount DESC, datefrom ASC
  LIMIT 1
);
```

Answer (score 3):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=499307f1550ad95f18f50c6ad69aee88)

You need [`DISTINCT ON`](https://zaiste.net/postgresql_distinct_on/) which filters the first row per group.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) 
    * 
 FROM table 
 ORDER BY name, amount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a nested inner join. Try this -

```
SELECT id, T2.name, T2.amount
FROM TABLE T
INNER JOIN (SELECT name, MAX(amount) amount
            FROM TABLE
            GROUP BY name) T2
ON T.amount = T2.amount
```

Comment: this will produce duplicates when there are 2 rows with same name and same amount, but different dates & ids.